# Configure Exception Site List in OpenJDK for Windows

Tags: java, oracle, exception, icedtea

I need to add certain URLs to the Java Exception Site List in a `Windows 10 server` which has OpenJDK installed. This has to be done to access these URLs from the Internet Explorer as these URLs are applets and they cannot be accessed from any other web browser.

I tried configuring exception site list in Oracle Java and it worked fine but could not achieve this in OpenJDK. I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774147/add-site-to-exception-list-in-openjdk-windows) that had a suggestion for configuring the exception site list for Oracle Java but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Came here to ask the same question, so giving this a bump rather than open my own question. Had a working deployment.config (and deployment.properties and exception.sites) with Oracle JRE, but while testing OpenJDK to switch, this looks like it's not reading the deployment.config?  And I'm having trouble finding any reference to that file in any OpenJDK documentation.  Would love to see an answer to this.